# Can't select Mailing Template in CiviMail after upgrading CiviCRM to 4.7.30

Tags: civimail, message-templates

After upgrading Civi to 4.7.30 the Template dropdown on the New Mailing screen has disappeared - the only option is to save to a new one:
[image: here's a screenshot.]

We upgraded from Civi 4.7.29 to 4.7.30 on Joomla 3.8.5, but the same happens in a pristine 4.7.30 on Wordpress 4.9.4 environment.

Opening the Javascript Console in Firefox gave me this:
[image: Console output]

It appears a ~/crmMailing/Templates.html is missing, called from Templates.js in the same folder /civicrm/ang/crmMailing/.

Anyone able to reproduce this?

Thanks for your help,

Comment: I thought I would compare with demo - and at Templates http://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2FmessageTemplates&reset=1 I get  "Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment"

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in 4.7.30. See [CRM-21759](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/projects/CRM/issues/CRM-21759?filter=allissues). There is now a [patch](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/11676) for it, or you can wait for 4.7.31.

> in 4.7.30 there is a call to a non existent angular templates file. This means that the Message Templates section of a new mailing doesn't load.